# MS SQL 2005 compare field containing square parenthesis

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using MS SQL Server 2005 (9.0.4035) and trying to find rows that contain the same data in a nvarchar(4000) field.  The field contains xml that has both opening and closing square parentheses.
Here is sample data:
    DataID   Data
    1        1
    2        1
    3        2]
    4        2]
    5        3[
    6        3[

Using the 'like' operator I expected to get 3 matching pairs, but my problem is that row 5 and 6 do not match each other, I only get back that rows 1 & 2 match, and 3 & 4 match.

I know MS SQL 2005 added regular expression support in queries but I did not expect them to evaluate field data as a regular expression, which I think it is doing.  Is there a mode that I need to enable to get the proper results?

Any help appreciated,
Ryan

**Edit:** Added sql statement used:

Select t1.DataID, t2.DataID From TestTable t1, TestTable t2
Where t1.DataID <> t2.DataID
and t1.Data like t2.Data

**Edit:** Answer
Using '=' operator works, but escaping the '[' does not.

Comment: Can you add the statement you tried, so we can get a better grip on your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your query to use = instead of LIKE and you'll get the results that you expect.  SQL 2005 T-SQL won't do regex - you'd need to use CLR functions for that - but the LIKE statment does do pattern matching.  '[' and ']' are reserved for the pattern matching in a like statment, and you'd have to escape them out if you intended for them to be equality matches.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx for info on the LIKE statement.

Either of the 2 queries below solved the problem in my tests...

```
--using equals operator...
Select t1.DataID, t2.DataID From TestTable t1, TestTable t2
Where t1.DataID <> t2.DataID
and t1.Data = t2.Data

--using replace to add an escape character.
Select t1.DataID, t2.DataID From TestTable t1, TestTable t2
Where t1.DataID <> t2.DataID
and t1.Data like REPLACE(t2.Data, '[', '\[') escape '\'
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott using '=' works.  I thought I tried that before but it was on Friday afternoon so maybe that was the problem.

I did try to escape the values before as well (by modifying the field value) with no such luck.  Using replace to escape the values does not return the correct result either.

Comment: strange that the escape didn't work for you - both queries worked on my SQL 2005 Standard dev box.